# How do I retrieve a custom property from a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

Greets,
I have a reference to a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder object:

```
Folder folder = _libraryClientContent.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(PATH_DEV_DOWNLOAD + GetDirectoryNameFromPathSP(filename));
```

The folder MAY contain a custom property.  How can I determine:

1. if this property exists on the folder
2. retrieve the property value if it exists?

Requirements:

- Works in SharePoint 2010 environment
- C# (or easily convertible)
- Uses all standard SharePoint resources; no add-ons, no GitHub, no CodePlex

I have a solution that works but takes way too much time.  I need something small and fast.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!
Current function:

```
    public bool IsToolDirectoryReadyForDeployment(string filename)
    {
        string folderName;
        string IsRFD;

        filename = filename.Substring(1);
        CollectionsGeneric.List<string> filenameParts = new CollectionsGeneric.List<string>(filename.Split('/'));

        folderName = filenameParts[0];

        List list = _libraryClientContent.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(LIST_SHARED_DOCS);
        _libraryClientContent.Load(
            list,
            property => property.RootFolder,
            property => property.RootFolder.Folders
            );
        _libraryClientContent.ExecuteQuery();

        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
        _libraryClientContent.Load(items,
            eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                item => item.DisplayName));
        _libraryClientContent.ExecuteQuery();

        ListItem toolItem = items.ToList<ListItem>().Single<ListItem>(li => (li.DisplayName == folderName));
        _libraryClientContent.Load(toolItem.FieldValuesForEdit);
        _libraryClientContent.ExecuteQuery();

        if (!toolItem.FieldValuesForEdit.FieldValues.TryGetValue("z_Deploy", out IsRFD))
            return false;
        else
            return IsRFD.Equals("Yes");

    }
```

Comment: So you currently use foreach loop as in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.properties(v=office.15).aspx, and that is slow, or what's the current solution?

Comment: Greets!  I've added the full current function.